# Format h:mm:ss moment no funciona para fecha IsoString

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

Estoy obteniendo unas fechas del tipo IsoString (2022-09-28T06:06:51.340Z), pero al formatear las fechas con moment la parte que corresponde al tiempo (h:mm:ss) no se formatea de forma correcta.

lo hago de esta forma:

```
moment(data.item.date_created).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss').toString()}}
```

A pesar de que las fechas tienen todas diferentes horas siempre muestra la misma hora para todas. Es como si para ese formato de tiempo no funcionara.

Estoy tratando de parsear las fechas dentro de un bucle para mostrar todas las fechas luego en una tabla. Creo que el error esta en el bucle ya que son miles de registros y tal vez a moment le toma un tiempo darle formato.

```
        <b-table table-class="table table-centered w-100" :striped="striped"
    :bordered="bordered" :small="small" :hover="hover" thead-tr-class="bg-light"
:items="data" :fields="fields" responsive="sm" :per-page="perPage"
:current-page="currentPage" :sort-by.sync="sortBy" :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
:filter="filter" :filter-included-fields="filterOn" @filtered="onFiltered">
    
 <template v-slot:cell(date_created)="data">
{{
  moment(data).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss ').toString()
}}
</template>
</b-table>
```

Comment: El código publicado funciona. Por lo que tu error debe estar en otro lado

Comment: @Yussef funciona fuera del bucle. Edite la pregunta. Gracias por responder.

Comment: eso no es solo javascript, verdad?  pon las etiquetas que correspondan, gracias

Comment: que lenguaje estás usando?

Comment: diria que es Vuejs, pero no tengo la certeza.  Veo en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55641538/10382744) del inglés un posible error de contrucción de la instrucción que está usando si está usando vue-moment.

Comment: Estoy utilizando vuejs

Comment: y si haces un console.log a data, que retorna???

Comment: @Yussef retorna la fecha en formato IsoString que es la que envia el backend.